# Google Cloud Storage Concurrency Control with Python / Apache Beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

I'm building a pipeline using Apache Beam in Python and I'm needing to avoid a race condition when writing to a file in Google Cloud Storage.

The following link describes how to use concurrency control in Google Cloud Storage using `gsutil`.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/ObjectVersioningandConcurrencyControl#concurrency-control

Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish the same thing using Python or the Apache Beam Python SDK?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to perform certain operations sequentially, your best bet is to do a group by key that gets them together.

For example, if you have two different elements writing to the same GCS file, you would want to do something like:

```
(my_collection | beam.Map(lambda x: (x['filename'], x))
               | beam.GroupByKey()
               | beam.Map(write_each_value))
```

By performing a `GroupByKey`, you ensure that elements with equal filenames go into the same worker, and are operated sequentially.

Comment: FWIW If you share more info about your use case, I may be able to give you a more tailored answer.

Comment: Here's a bit more background: I have an IoT device that sends packets up the GCS about every 30 minutes. This data is sent up in binary. My goal is to go to GCS, parse the binary into a CSV, group by device_id and day, then end up with one CSV that has all the data for a given user on a given day. As I've been testing the pipeline, I have been using batch processing, but I will eventually be using streaming. How can I guarantee that two workers won't try writing to the same file at the same time in the case of streaming?

Comment: I see what you mean. Is it reasonable to have a single thread that monitors the directory for new files, and emits events ? Something like so:  `beam.Create(['gs://my_directory']) | beam.FlatMap(monitor_directory_continuously) | beam.Reshuffle() | MyOperationPerFile()`. - This pipeline would monitor the directory in a single thread, and reshuffle file names to other workers to analyze them